# How to fill MaterialUI tabs with a given color?

Tags: material-ui

In the [customized tabs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#customized-tabs) section, the docs give an example of how to inject your own CSS to the frameworks components, and I want to utilize this but I am unsure how. I'd like for my active tabs to be filled with a set color altogether, instead of there simply being an underline under an active tab. Does anybody know how I would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below does hides the indicator and fills the Tab with the selected color:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { AppBar, Tabs, Tab, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyle = makeStyles(theme => ({
  indicator: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent", 
  },
  selected: {
    background: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
}));

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const classes = useStyle();
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs
          classes={{
            indicator: classes.indicator
          }}
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <Tab label="Item One" classes={{ selected: classes.selected }} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" classes={{ selected: classes.selected }} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" classes={{ selected: classes.selected }} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, you want to change the background color of the selected (active) tab
it can be done with css class itself

[image]

you can give your respective background color
there is an css class which is getting applied based on the selected tab

```
.Mui-selected {
   background : limegreen;
}
```

Incase that css is not getting applied , you can override the css

```
.Mui-selected {
   background : limegreen !important;
}
```

Hope this answer solves your need.
Incase any other needed, post that as comment, will try to answer for that